# How can I write more efficient code for the function below?

Tags: javascript

This function shows/hides select tags for locations to be selected bases on employee designation. Code I have written works fine but I feel it can be more efficient.

```
//according to different designation different set of locations options gets activated
function location_served_option_by_designation(filter)
    {   
        var area_display_setting;
        var city_display_setting;
        var region_display_setting;
        var zone_display_setting;
        var country_display_setting;
        var location_title;

        switch(filter.value.toLowerCase()){
            case 'bm':
                area_display_setting = 'none';
                city_display_setting = 'flex';
                region_display_setting = 'flex';
                zone_display_setting = 'flex';
                country_display_setting = 'flex';

                location_title = 'area';
                break
            case 'abm':
                area_display_setting = 'none';
                city_display_setting = 'flex';
                region_display_setting = 'flex';
                zone_display_setting = 'flex';
                country_display_setting = 'flex';

                location_title = 'area';
                break
            case 'rsm':
                area_display_setting = 'none';
                city_display_setting = 'none';
                region_display_setting = 'none';
                zone_display_setting = 'flex';
                country_display_setting = 'flex';

                location_title = 'region';
                break
            case 'zsm':
                area_display_setting = 'none';
                city_display_setting = 'none';
                region_display_setting = 'none';
                zone_display_setting = 'none';
                country_display_setting = 'flex';

                location_title = 'zone';
                break
            case 'nsm':
                area_display_setting = 'none';
                city_display_setting = 'none';
                region_display_setting = 'none';
                zone_display_setting = 'none';
                country_display_setting = 'none';

                location_title = 'country';
                break
        }

        location_served_area.style.display = area_display_setting;
        selected_served_area.options[0].selected = 'true';

        location_served_city.style.display = city_display_setting;
        selected_served_city.options[0].selected = 'true';

        location_served_region.style.display = region_display_setting;
        selected_served_region.options[0].selected = 'true';

        location_served_zone.style.display = zone_display_setting;
        selected_served_zone.options[0].selected = 'true';

        location_served_country.style.display = country_display_setting;
        selected_served_country.options[0].selected = 'true';

        location_served_title.innerText = location_title[0].toUpperCase() + location_title.slice(1);
    }
```

Image of the HTML Markup | here selected designation is "BM" therefore country:india, zone:central zone, region: chhattisgarh and city:Durg1 is activated and based on the city areas get activated to choose employees service area. In case the designation was 'ZSM' only country select tag will get activated and as per country zones to choose from will appear as checkboxes.
[image]

Comment: “Premature optimization is the root of all evil“ - Donald Knuth

Comment: @Skusku Thanks for the advice, it's really helpful. I like another similar version "make it work | make it better | make it fast". I will try to follow your advice thank you

Comment: Logically your code is correct. The only thing I would like to suggest, to remove duplicity and redundancy.  Move similar operations to a separate function. 
1. function for setting option value true every time.
2. function to set the display setting, just pass the arguments.

Comment: After case 'bm': you could remove: 
                area_display_setting = 'none';
                city_display_setting = 'flex';
                region_display_setting = 'flex';
                zone_display_setting = 'flex';
                country_display_setting = 'flex';

                location_title = 'area';
                break;"
    since the next statement contains the same logic. For the rest of the code I would not simplify more by making it more generic because this often leads to unreadable and inflexible code and it will not speed up things.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would use `if ... else` statements instead of `switch`, give the variables values from the start and change them only if they meet my criteria. In our case if the filter value is equal to "nsm" the values stay the same so we can check for the other cases. In javaScript is recommended to camelCase the variable names and keep the names fairly short and relevant.
This is how I would DRY the code:

```
function byDesignation(filter) {   
  let filterValue = filter.value.toLowerCase();
  let area = "none";
  let city = "none";
  let region = "none";
  let zone = "none";
  let country = "none";
  let locationTitle = "country";

  if (filterValue === "zsm") {
    country = "flex";
    locationTitle = "zone";
  } else if (filterValue === "rsm") {
    locationTitle = "region";
    zone = "flex";
    country = "flex";
  } else if (filterValue === "abm" || filterValue === "bm") {
    locationTitle = "area";
    city = "flex";
    region = "flex";
    zone = "flex";
    country = "flex";  
  }
  // the rest of the function
  // ...
}
```